# how to get the screen name of the celebrity from their names

Tags: angularjs, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I am Developing a App which would identify a celebrity from their photo and give their name.

I want to get their Twitter screen name from the normal name.

eg Screen name of Barak Obama is @BarackObama

I want to retrive @BarakObama from "Barak Obama"

I am using "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json?q=Barak%20Obama&page=10"

But in the result data there are no VERIFIED accounts.

How to get the screen names of the celebrities using twitter API

Comment: You can't. You could try to do the trick by yourself, maybe you should check for verified accounts on the results and keep the one that you find

Answer (score 0):

This is not feasible, because Twitter user names are not always their real names.  Some examples from the top 100 most-followed celebrities:

- Demi Lovato is @ddlovato
- LeBron James is @kingjames
- Neil Patrick Harris is @actuallynph

...and so on.

Doing this in a programmatic way is certainly possible, but is not something that is possible in the Twitter API.